# Gmail and other private servers mark legitimate email as SPAM

Tags: postfix, spam-marked

The mail server configuration is driving me crazy.
Emails sent from my own private server are being banned, again by Gmail and other private servers.

I checked gmail headers and SPF, DKIM and DMARC pass the exam. Attached the headers of a blocked email sent and blocked by gmail (sent to the spam folder)

```
Delivered-To: t***@gmail.com
Received: by 10.129.84.197 with SMTP id i188csp307475ywb;
    Tue, 28 Mar 2017 08:09:36 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.223.179.15 with SMTP id j15mr28236175wrd.62.1490713776657;
    Tue, 28 Mar 2017 08:09:36 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <x****@e****a.com>
Received: from sd-****.h****t.net (sd-****.h****t.net. [62.***.***.202])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id d9si3721691wmf.26.2017.03.28.08.09.36
    for <t***@gmail.com>
    (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
    Tue, 28 Mar 2017 08:09:36 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of x****@e****a.com designates 62.***.***.202 as permitted sender) client-ip=62.***.***.202;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   dkim=pass header.i=@e****a.com;
   spf=pass (google.com: domain of x****@e****a.com designates 62.***.***.202 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=x****@e****a.com;
   dmarc=pass (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=e****a.com
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1]) by sd-****.h****t.net (Postfix) with ESMTP id 23010E1804BD for <t***@gmail.com>; Tue, 28 Mar 2017 17:09:06 +0200 (CEST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=e****a.com; h= user-agent:message-id:references:in-reply-to:organization :subject:subject:from:from:date:date:content-type:content-type :mime-version; s=default; t=1490713742; x=1492528143; bh=3ja/eI3 QdMpadvw414LY9BFcUewLWEwqdI4hsKcMJJM=; b=j6otfwG+Z3810Oy1UDib4qM NJ580B6v06J9DVKRoP8orJnGtd3UpP5l2ingbwaR5c9q4X/XJ9NAFVe9d4TW76Nv sNAMimkRVYX78SS47gRVlCRmHDwab1FwgdsAP6yJRBpBhT76X/nydqbqfkkQampr FDWehLeYjk0w5XgZUilA=
X-Virus-Scanned: Debian amavisd-new at sd-****.h****t.net
Received: from sd-****.h****t.net ([127.0.0.1]) by localhost (sd-****.h****t.net [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10026) with ESMTP id cZ7SDTl25__u for <t***@gmail.com>; Tue, 28 Mar 2017 17:09:02 +0200 (CEST)
Received: from webmail.e***.com (localhost [IPv6:::1]) by sd-****.h****t.net (Postfix) with ESMTP id B5787E180487 for <t***@gmail.com>; Tue, 28 Mar 2017 17:09:02 +0200 (CEST)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;     boundary="=_63e0609e24a7c5c6e72a2b53077f53c2"
Date: Tue, 28 Mar 2017 17:09:02 +0200
From: X*** **** - E*** K*** <x****@e****a.com>
To: t***@gmail.com
Subject: Fwd: Re: --- Subject of the message ---
Organization: E*** K****
In-Reply-To: <9f2d7aa8380dcf31e2a7af4795a1463d@e****a.com>
References: <CAMhvi0=PAuUOpg4eNmYn+gckaRhP6wFMMyO-frJeY5=gPC-qVg@mail.gmail.com> <9f2d7aa8380dcf31e2a7af4795a1463d@e****a.com>
Message-ID: <794731b396abba6212312e17219e6d7f@e****a.com>
X-Sender: x****@e****a.com
User-Agent: Roundcube Webmail/1.1.5

--=_63e0609e24a7c5c6e72a2b53077f53c2
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

--- Here the content of the message ---

--=_63e0609e24a7c5c6e72a2b53077f53c2--
```

EDIT: Result from senderbase:

```
Details
IP Address  62.***.***.202
Fwd/Rev DNS Match  Help Yes

Email Reputation  Help  Neutral
Web Reputation  Help    Neutral

Last Day    Last Month
Email Volume  Help  0.0 1.9
Volume Change  Help -100%  ↓    

Hostname    sd-****.h****t.net
Domain  Help    poneytelecom.eu
Network Owner  Help Free SAS
Blacklists  Help
bl.spamcop.net  Not Listed
cbl.abuseat.org Not Listed
pbl.spamhaus.org    Not Listed
sbl.spamhaus.org    Not Listed
```

Comment: Your domains or IP range may be on a blacklist or lack sufficient reputation. Most of us here let someone else like AWS SES or Sendgrid handle the sending.

Comment: I have checked already that in all this links https://www.spamhaus.org/,  https://mxtoolbox.com, https://ers.trendmicro.com/reputations, http://ipremoval.sms.symantec.com/lookup/ and all them show the server is not listed in any list. https://www.mail-tester.com/spf-dkim-check scores my mails sent as 10/10 too

Comment: well without real info it's impossible to give real help.  if you don't have consistent mailflow and good reputation  (senderbase) you'll go to spam.

Comment: What info do you need?  This is the result from senderbase, it marks the server as neutral and not listed in any blacklist (I'll paste the result in the question for better reading)

Comment: `Attached the headers of a blocked email sent and blocked by gmail (sent to the spam folder)` - If the email wound up in the recipients spam folder then it was in fact not blocked, nor "banned" as you state in your question. It was accepted by Gmail and then categorized as spam either by Gmail's internal spam filter or by the recipient himself/herself. Focus on the content of the message as the likely cause. Your DKIM, SPF, and DMARC are fine, as evidenced in the headers.

Comment: Is there any method/rules to check the content of the message? There is really nothing special in it, no attached documents at all. Just a HTML email without any suspicious link (just a mailto and a link to my website), in fact, a very normal business email, communication between two employees.

Comment: It could be the fact this the format is HTML or it could be the hyperlinks. Try sending it without the hyperlinks and without any images/signature if they pull content from external sources. If the result is the same then try sending a plain text email as a test.

Comment: @joeqwerty, I think you hit the nail ! . I have tried removing all html hrefs from my email signature and now the mail got straight into the inbox . You are the man !  reply to the question and I will mark it as valid.

Comment: I've already upvoted this question but I think you should post Edit 2 as an actual answer. On [se] sites, explicitly answering your own question is better than editing the question to incorporate an answer (a practice that might make more sense on a web forum). That way, people can upvote your answer separate to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I marked the reply from joequerty as the solution but I have to say that in the end it did not solve the problem, although it helped so much.

This is how I solved it in case anyone else needs a hand. In order to know what is causing the email to be forwarded to the spam folders, you should add a DMARC record using your postmaster's address so that gmail and other mail providers will send you logs helping you to find out the clue of non-working or bad configured email servers. Once you configure the DMARC, will have to wait, probably hours until your first diagnosis emails arrive. Meanwhile, you can check your settings with mxtoolbox.com and intodns.com tools until you don't get any error. Make sure your SPF and DKIM records (of course DMARC as well) are valid. If after all this steps, your email is still marked as spam you can use the Hotmail (postmaster.live.com) and Gmail (postmaster.google.com) postmaster tools. You will probably need to get a good reputation from them before your emails are delivered to the recipients inbox as they should. Good luck !

Answer (score 12):

> Attached the headers of a blocked email sent and blocked by gmail (sent to the spam folder)

If the email wound up in the recipients spam folder then it was in fact not blocked, nor "banned" as you state in your question. It was accepted by Gmail and then categorized as spam either by Gmail's internal spam filter or by the recipient himself/herself. Focus on the content of the message as the likely cause. Your DKIM, SPF, and DMARC are fine, as evidenced in the headers.

> Is there any method/rules to check the content of the message? There is really nothing special in it, no attached documents at all. Just a HTML email without any suspicious link (just a mailto and a link to my website), in fact, a very normal business email, communication between two employees.

It could be the fact that the format is HTML or it could be the hyperlinks. Try sending it without the hyperlinks and without any images/signature if they pull content from external sources. If the result is the same then try sending a plain text email as a test.

Comment: I have to say that although this solution may helped it finally did not solve the problem. I thought it did because in Gmail, after I marked one email as "not spam", started to deliver the messages correctly. But I tried on a new account and it kept sending it to the spam folder. So I started digging and I used mxtoolbox to search for errors (dns, email, etc..). I corrected them all  until there were no errors and by now hotmail.com seems to forward mails correctly. But gmail keeps marking any email as spam until the recipient previously marks the message as "not spam".

Comment: In addition I am sending everyday multiple emails to some (gmail, hotmail, yahoo, etc..) inboxes I created for the porpouse to get a better reputation, which seems to be very important for them. But I feel blind in the case of other private servers, I am not sure if the emails will arrive or not although SPF, DKIM, DMARC and all possible configuration pass the filters. I start to think that Microsoft does not like postfix and only Exchange could deliver properly to the recipients inbox..

Comment: OK. One important thing to understand is that if the email is in the recipients Junk/Spam folder then the email was not blocked or rejected by the mail server. That is an important distinction to understand. If it's in the mailbox then the server did accept it. The email was filtered internally, not externally.

Comment: I understand, that's why the guys from Microsoft keep telling me everything is ok with the server. But the case is that clients are not used to check the spam folder, and my customers do not like to ask theirs to check the spam for the non delivered missing message .. It's very annoying. I have been running debian servers for many years and this did not happen to me in the past..

Answer (score 0):

you need to check if earlier records from sender domain or ip were clean, if the server had sent lot of spam or has lot of email bounces then it could be in the blacklist of http://www.sorbs.net/ or smilar other sites which track and blacklist email servers

you need check your domain or ip on these sites and some servers refer this data to check blacklisting of ip's or domains

**some of the sites to check are as below**

https://www.dnswl.org

http://www.sorbs.net

https://www.dnswl.org/

http://ipadmin.junkemailfilter.com/remove.php

If you are clean on all above sites then your email can pass and deliver in inbox
It still depends upon the receiver email settings whether your email will land in inbox or spam

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this didn't work. The IPs are not blacklisted. The problem is that due to hotmail and Google spam policies, if the IP is new and hasn't sent many emails they mark it as spam, although it is not. The real solution here is to send daily emails to addresses in those services, with insistence and patience they finally got straight into the inbox.